# How to construct object from multiple tables in Go

Tags: database, go

I'm trying to find the best way to work with objects represented by multiple database tables.

For database access I wrapped sqlx with my own type and then defined some methods:

```
type DB struct {
    *sqlx.DB
}
func (db *DB) GetSomething(id uint32) *Something {} 
func (db *DB) AddSomething(*Something) {}
```

It works nice for objects that map one-to-one with single database table. I see a couple of ways to work with multi-table objects:

1. Define methods on *DB that do selects from multiple tables and then
   construct an object. Save is similiar.
2. Create a layer on top of *DB which would construct an object.
3. Do not construct an object, use its parts.

I rather prefer number 2, but need help on how to design it in Go.

Comment: have you looked at existing ORMs?

Comment: I prefer to write my own sql.

Comment: Can you expand on what #2 would look like?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer asked if you looked at existing ORMs, not adviced you to use one. I think that if it will not actually answer your question it will help you to ask more productive one.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Specially, Proof-read before posting!

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer asked if you looked at existing ORMs, not adviced you to use one. I think that if it will not actually answer your question it will help you to ask more productive one.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Specially, Proof-read before posting!

Comment: @ZAky right, I meant looking at the implementation patterns of others, and implicitly wondered if OP really wants to write yet another ORM. BTW I have written one, but it it's flat and doesn't use relations at all, so this issue was never something I've dealt with.

Comment: Thank you for comments. Probably my question wasn't very clear. I will try to think this over and update it in a couple of days. In relation to ORM's: gorm (the only one i looked at) constructs queries based on metadata, I have concrete queries for data manipulation, gorm uses metadata to construct multi table objects, i prefer concrete methods for that too. It looks orthogonal to my question.

Comment: Gorp specifically supports selecting view-like objects that join tables (https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp)

Answer (score 0):

If just to reduce the duplication of code each time you want `User`, put that somewhere that deals with users. `UserService` if you will, along with `createUser` and `isUserNameAvailable`. Some would go even further and create separate layer just for data retrieval and persistence (DAO layer), for me that's a bit too much of boilerplate.

Sometimes you'll find that you probably don't need a separate method at all. You're pulling a complex report from the DB, but the only time you need it is to return via single rest endpoint. The only time you need user by username and password hash is during login - just use it in unside the login(username,password) method. In those cases, just call `sqlx` directly in your business methods.

Comment: Let's say i have User { name string, addresses []Address }, and two UserService methods Get() and Save(). How UserService get/save addresses? What if i need user without addresses? What if Address { []Phone } ?

Comment: If only user can have adresses and phones, I would initially put it all under user service to keep things simple. If the logic around address handling grows too complex over time, I'd move it outside user service to keep it tight.